# java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already

Tags: java, android, timer

Having a problem with the `Timer` where it shows this error. I have a `Timer` that schedules a `TimerTask` (close). Then, inside the `TimerTask` I schedule the next `TimerTask` and so on. To my understanding this should work, but when I run it the app has the "Stopped Working" error.

`levelCreationTimer.schedule(close, 1000);` <= This is called in the OnCreate.

```
Timer levelCreationTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask close = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (points < 10) {
            switch (randNum.nextInt(2)) {
                case 0:
                    locationBlimps[0][0] = 0;
                    locationBlimps[0][1] = 0;
                    locationBlimps[1][0] = -1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    locationBlimps[0][0] = 4;
                    locationBlimps[0][1] = 4;
                    locationBlimps[1][0] = -1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (locationBlimps[i][0] != -1) {
            final int final_i = i;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sky[locationBlimps[final_i][1]][locationBlimps[final_i][0]].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scissors);
                }
            });
            i++;
        }
        levelCreationTimer.schedule(far, 1000);
    }
};
TimerTask far = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int j = 0;
        while (locationBlimps[j][0] != -1) {
            final int final_j = j;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sky[locationBlimps[final_j][1]][locationBlimps[final_j][0]].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scissors);
                    obstacles[locationBlimps[final_j][1]][locationBlimps[final_j][0]] = true;
                }
            });
            j++;
        }
        levelCreationTimer.schedule(last, 1000);
    }
};
TimerTask last = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int k = 0;
        while (locationBlimps[k][0] != -1) {
            final int final_k = k;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sky[locationBlimps[final_k][1]][locationBlimps[final_k][0]].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sky);
                    obstacles[locationBlimps[final_k][1]][locationBlimps[final_k][0]] = false;
                }
            });
            k++;
        }
        levelCreationTimer.schedule(close, 10000);
    }
};
```

I also tried adding

```
        levelCreationTimer.cancel();
        levelCreationTimer = new Timer();
```

before each `schedule` in-order to delete the schedule, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: The exception message implies that a TimerTask object can only be scheduled once. Try cloning the objects (close, far, last) before you schedule them. `TimerTask task = close.clone(); levelCreationTimer.schedule(task, 1000);`

Comment: @mkasberg Wouldn't creating a new Timer solve the problem then?

Comment: No, not if a TimerTask can only be scheduled once and you pass the new Timer the same TimerTask.

Comment: Read the documentation of TimerTask here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html It says that you can schedule a TimerTask for one-time or repeated execution. You are scheduling it for one-time execution. Read the documentation on Timer here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html You need to pass in a `period` parameter when you call `schedule()` if you want repeated execution. You can either use my original suggestion to clone your tasks, or refactor your code to use repeating timers.

Comment: The 'clone()' method doesn't work because the TimerTask is abstract (I can't create objects from it).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating classes that extend `TimerTask` and then I schedule instances of the classes.

```
class MyClass1 extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //my code
        levelCreationTimer.schedule(new MyClass2(),1000);
        //scheduling the next TimerTask ^
    }
}
class MyClass2 extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //my code
        levelCreationTimer.schedule(new MyClass1(),1000);
        //scheduling the next TimerTask ^
    }
}
```